# How to round a small double value with limited decimals c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, types, rounding

I have a small double value

ex: 0.00000005;

I need to increase it by 135% and the result should be 0.0000001175...

Then  i need to round it to 0.00000012;(because of a 10 characters length limitation in my app where i need to input my new value as a string)

After the calculation i'm getting this result 1.175E-07.
How can i change the exponential notation of my value  to a normal form, and round it ?(Considering my limitation, of course....)

```
 floating_value =Math.Round((floating_value + ((floating_value / 100) * 135)),8);

 TP = Convert.ToString(floating_value);

 IWebElement SearchInputBox = _ww.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("input-box")));

 SearchInputBox.Clear();
 SearchInputBox.SendKeys(TP);
```

Comment: What code you have written for this? Without knowing what logic you have applied for this it would not be easy to tell where and what problem is and off course what solution is.

Comment: Your question is essentially a _set of requirements_. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Exponential notation is just a presentation of number, don't worry about it.

Round number with [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx) function. And print it with 8 digits after comma with `ToString("F8")`. Also, there are other formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
double a = 0.0000001175;
var result = Math.Round(a,8);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("F8"));
```

Will output: `0.00000012`

Example: https://ideone.com/uV8f0X

Your case:

```
floating_value =Math.Round((floating_value + ((floating_value / 100) * 135)),8);

TP = floating_value.ToString("F8");
```

Comment: Is there any other method? This one isn't working for me...I'm getting the same exp value... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @andrewjonson use `floating_value.ToString("F8");`